# Not able to use twitter api on postman because of error

Tags: twitter, postman

I am trying to use this api https://www.postman.com/twitter/workspace/twitter-s-public-workspace/collection/9956214-784efcda-ed4c-4491-a4c0-a26470a67400?ctx=documentation

I forked it to my workspace and edited the variables using my access, bearer, consumer etc...

However when I try a sample by going to User Lookup > User by ID and I put the ID and press Send it says
"title": "Unauthorized",
"type": "about:blank",
"status": 401,
"detail": "Unauthorized"

I think the reason is because when I fork the twitter api to my workspace it doesn't fork over the two environments top right "Twitter API V2" and "Twitter Premium API" even though I am putting my token in the variables tab it shows the error above why?

Can someone show me how would you access the twitter api v2 public workspace above and be able to use it?

Comment: Have you tried also forking the environment files to the Workspace?

Comment: @DannyDainton  I think so, what I did is go to that workspace > forked the Twitter API v2 from collections and forked Twitter API v2 from environments. Then went back to my workspace and went to the top right where it said "No Environment" and I added in the twitter api v2 environment and filled the 5 blanks yet still gave me unauthorized error... Not sure what I'm doin wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You should set 'Twitter API V2' authorization bearer token.

[image: Twitter API V2 authorization]

Or set each api authorization.

[image: Api authorization]

If there is no environment setting, setting the Variables value also works.

[image: Twitter API V2 Variables setting]